# JavaFX 8 - How to get Backspace key pressed on HTMLEditor?

Tags: java, javafx-8, keyevent

I want to mark a dialog as dirty when any key on the keyboard is pressed. Therefore I have this code:

```
editor.setOnKeyPressed(event -> dirtyProperty.set(true));
```

`editor` is a `HTMLEditor` control. It works for every `KeyEvent` (CTRL, etc. are also catched with this), but not for the Backspace and Delete key events. What I'm doing wrong here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The line

```
editor.setOnKeyPressed(event -> dirtyProperty.set(true));
```

is shorthand of and thus equivalent to

```
editor.addEventHandler(KeyEvent.KEY_PRESSED, event -> dirtyProperty.set(true));
```

`HTMLEditor` seems to be consuming <kbd>Backspace</kbd> and <kbd>Delete</kbd> key events, before these events reach to the key handler defined like above.

Instead of adding event handler, add a key filter to the editor

```
editor.addEventFilter(KeyEvent.KEY_PRESSED, event -> dirtyProperty.set(true));
```

Since event filters are invoked as soon as when the event is received, before any event handlers. Whereas event handlers are invoked when the event is in bubbling phase, namely when the event is going back to parent node.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if this is a bug, the code that you posted doesn't work as intended but the following does work.

```
editor.addEventFilter(KeyEvent.KEY_PRESSED, (KeyEvent event) -> {
      System.out.println(event.getCode());
});
```

May be someone else can answer it better or you may file an [issue with the JavaFX team](https://javafx-jira.kenai.com/secure/Dashboard.jspa).

Comment: works fine thank you! I've marked the answer of Uluk Biy as solution, because it was first and is described.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
final HTMLEditor editor = new HTMLEditor();
    editor.setOnKeyReleased(new EventHandler<KeyEvent>() {
        public void handle(KeyEvent t) {
            if (t.getCode() == KeyCode.BACK_SPACE) {
                System.out.println("backspace pressed...");
            }
        }
    });
```